# Can't play video streamed with VLC using html5 video tag and Apache server

Tags: html, apache, http, video, vlc

I have an Apache server with a webpage written in HTML5 that has a video tag to play video from a webcam. I use VLC to stream the video over HTTP in OGG. My problem is that I can play the video in a browser from the computer where the server is allocated, but from another computer the video window is blank.

I have done some tests to try to solve my problem:

- if I put a video file in *htdocs* and the corresponding line in the html file, the video is played.
- If the stream is a video file instead of video from the webcam, there is the same problem.
- With VLC option *Open Network Stream* the video is played successfully from another computer.
- When I have the blank window problem, with wireshark I don't see the stream being downloaded.

This is how I use the video tag:

```
       <video id = "myVideo" src="http://localhost:8081/stream.ogg" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```

I would appreciate any suggestion, thank you in advance!
Kiko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> http://localhost

Localhost will always point to your local computer. So if you run the application on the server the video file will actually resides on, it will find the file.

But if you are running the script on another computer, this computer will actually look locally, where the video file does not resides.

Try replacing http://localhost with the external IP-adres of your server.

Comment: No it won't, it will point wherever its DNS resolves to.127.0.0.1 will always point to the local computer.

Comment: True. I just assumed the default config for the level of this question. But fair is fair, you are right.